# Measure value of fact table is wrong in Tableau

Tags: mysql, sql, join, tableau-api, fact-table

I had created a fact table and when i deploy the cube and visualise the data in Tableau, aggregate value is getting populated. Below is my fact table(where id1=1) with header changed for readable purpose. if i drop revenue2 measure in tableau against id2(Year dimension), sum of  column revenue2(49,08,238) is getting visualized instead of 701177

```
id1 id2 pos neg scre ne id3  gdp   reven1    reven2 id4 market    share     closerate
1   1   268 284 552 51  2   14712   715905  701177  1   1400120   5.2       516.8333363
1   1   268 284 552 51  2   14712   715905  701177  2   21620183  9.4       516.8333363
1   1   268 284 552 51  2   14712   715905  701177  3   160096    6.2       516.8333363
1   1   268 284 552 51  2   14712   715905  701177  6   49723135  8.1       516.8333363
1   1   268 284 552 51  2   14712   715905  701177  7   4445702   2.7       516.8333363
1   1   268 284 552 51  2   14712   715905  701177  8   32088391  6.6       516.8333363
1   1   268 284 552 51  2   14712   715905  701177  9   4444908   10.7      516.8333363
```

suggest me where if my join is wrong or i need to change any properties in tableau.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that is what Tableau normally does. It is summing the measure "reven2" and grouping by the dimension "id2". It is not doing that in the view you shared because you have other columns in there, like id4, market, and share, which are different - it can't group on those.

Comment: Ya i agree with you but while visualising the data to client, that "reven2" is not exact data, It's manipulated data.is there any way to handle this scenario  in fact table? @wavery